# set.add() returning error

Tags: python, set

I am trying to add items to an empty set from a list after checking if the page is rooted with the isRooted function.

```
uniqueUrl = set()
for url in urlList:
    if(isRooted(rootURL,url[0])):
        uniqueURL.add(url[0])
```

This is the error I am recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python32\webcrawl.py", line 119, in crawl
  uniqueURL.add(url[0])
NameError: global name 'uniqueURL' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caps are different in the two variables.